# React Hooks - change parent style to reflect child onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I'm pretty new to React and I'm attempting to get my head around hooks. I have a button component that I've successfully changed the style for when clicked, but ideally I want the parent of that component (the app) to pick up the change so I can add a style class to that too.

Here's a simplified version of what I have so far:

Parent:

```
function App() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Main className={navOpen ? 'active': ''}> // <---this is what I'm trying to update
        <header className="Nav">
          <NavBurger />
          <Nav>
            <NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink>
          </Nav>
        </header>
        <div className="content">
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </div>
      </Main>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and here's the child component:

```
function NavBurger() {
  const openMenu = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <NavButton className={isOpen ? 'active': ''} onClick={openMenu}> // <-- This works just fine
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </NavButton>
  );
}

export default NavBurger;
```

Is this even possible? I've been trying a few things but still can't get it to work.

Comment: Why not use app-level state store (like redux or similar)? If you need to lift up the state then having a global store may make your life easier on the long run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rethink about the `isOpen` scope, as for this example, you might want it to be available for `App`, therefore you should [Lift the State up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up).

> Often, several components need to reflect the same changing data. We recommend lifting the shared state up to their closest common ancestor.

```
function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(open => !open);
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Main className={navOpen ? 'active' : ''}>
        <header className="Nav">
          <NavBurger isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle}/>
        </header>
      </Main>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function NavBurger({ isOpen, toggle }) {
  return (
    <NavButton className={isOpen ? 'active' : ''} onClick={toggle}>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </NavButton>
  );
}
```

> Note that this question has nothing to do with [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and more about [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Comment: Thank you. I think I get what you're saying, but it still isn't working. It's telling me 'isOpen' is not defined within NavBurger.js

Comment: be sure you use the props of the component